# Java.io.file for android using assetmanager

Tags: java, android

How do I convert this code for Android?

```
 POSModel model = new POSModelLoader()  
    .load(new File("en-pos-maxent.bin"));
```

I have this code on my onCreate

```
final AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
final InputStream inputStream = null;
```

then I try to access my assets by this code

```
inputStream = assetManager.open("en-pos-maxent.bin");
```

then I tried to pass inputStream to the code new File(inputStream);

Not sure how I would pass the bin file to the model.
I don't know how I would use inputstream for a java.io.File parameter?

EDIT:
[Here's what I did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbhZX.png)

[Here's the original code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElNKH.png)

Comment: `then I tried to pass inputStream to the code new File(inputStream);`. Impossible. But please explain why you try to do do. Its completely unclear what you want to do with your 'file' in assets.

Comment: So your model can only load info from a File object. Not from an InputStream. Thats your problem. `.load(inputstream)` is not available?

Comment: I am trying to access the .bin file from my assets to I can initialize a function from the library. It needs the "en-pos-maxent.bin" file. so I tried my usual way of accessing the asset using assetmanager then assigning it to an inputStream.then i passed inputstream in .load(new File(inputsream)) but it didn't work.

Comment: You are telling nothing new. We already knew that. You only repeated yourself. And you did not give the info i asked for.  I also wonder why you did not react at Chetan's answer.

Comment: i tried to use his suggestion but it didn't work. i don't really know.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Below Method :

```
private  File getFileFromAsset(){
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStream outputStream =null;
        File file =null;

            try {
                inputStream = assetManager.open("en-pos-maxent.bin");
                file = new File(getCacheDir(), "en-pos-maxent.bin");
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024]; // or other buffer size
                    int read;

                    while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
                    }
                outputStream.flush();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); // handle exception, define IOException and others

        } finally {
            try {
                if(outputStream!=null)
                    outputStream.close();
                if(inputStream!=null)
                    inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }}
            return file;

    }
```